# Logic error php / Symfony

Tags: php, api, symfony, logic

Hey guys I have a little problem I will try to explain you (is not a technic problem just logic) :

So I have an mongoDB database and I send and receive message (I am doing a message system from user to user) and when I try to see the message and I am doing this for an API.

The problem is that when I do the post method I have to pass as parameter this :

```
{
    "id_transmitter": 2,
    "token": "eyJ0...",
    "id_receiver": 4
}
```

Response :

```
{
"success": "true",
"message": [
    [
        {
            "id": "5b71861fe138231d423a95ef",
            "content": "5",
            "transmitter": 2,
            "Receiver": 4,
            "send_at": {
                "sec": 1534166559,
                "inc": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "5b71861ce138231d423a95ee",
            "content": "4",
            "transmitter": 2,
            "Receiver": 4,
            "send_at": {
                "sec": 1534166556,
                "inc": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "5b718619e138231d423a95ed",
            "content": "3",
            "transmitter": 2,
            "Receiver": 4,
            "send_at": {
                "sec": 1534166553,
                "inc": 1
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "5b718615e138231d423a95ec",
            "content": "2",
            "transmitter": 2,
            "Receiver": 4,
            "send_at": {
                "sec": 1534166549,
                "inc": 1
            }
        }
    ]
],
"more": 1
}
```

As you can see I pass the receiver and the message to see and here is the problem I show only the message that we received OR that we send but not both at same time ... or I have to do 2 repository one with all received and one other with sended and when I will try to show by order of date that will print first one repo and after the other ... and not all together like a converstion should be ...

Here you can find how i did :

```
/**
 *
 * @Rest\Post(
 *     path = "/message/user/list/{page}",
 *     name = "api_message_list"
 * )
 */
public function UserSeeMessageAction(Request $request, $page)
{
    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb');
    $messages = $dm->getRepository('AppBundle:MessageUser')->findBy(array
    (
        'idTransmitter' => ($request->get('id_transmitter')),
        'idReceiver' => ($request->get('id_receiver')),
        ), array('id' => 'DESC'));

    //return new JsonResponse([
    //    'success' => "true",
    //    'message' => $messages,
    //    'more' => 0,
    //]);
    if (($request->get('id_receiver')) == null) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Receveur non renseigné"
        ]);
    }
    if (($request->get('id_transmitter')) == null) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Transmetteur non renseigné"
        ]);
    }

    if (!isset($messages)) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Pas de messages pour les utilisateurs"
        ]);
    }

    $arrayCollection = array();

    $entities = 4;
    $y = 0;
    $x = 0;
    foreach($messages as $message) {
        if ($y >= ($page * $entities)) {
            return new JsonResponse([
                'success' => "true",
                'message' => $arrayCollection,
                'more' => 1,
            ]);
        }
        if ($y >= (($page - 1) * $entities) and $y < (($page) * $entities)) {
            $x = 1;
            $arrayCollection[] = array(
                $message,
            );
        }
        $y += 1;
    }
    if ($x == 1) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "true",
            'message' => $arrayCollection,
            'more' => 0,
        ]);
    }
    return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => "false",
        'message' => "Plus de message",
    ]);
}
```

So for resume : my problem is that I print only sended message or received but not all together

Exemple :

Like it should be :

> Hello i am one (send by one)
>
> Hello one ! I am two (send by two)
>
> How are you (send by one)
>
> Fine (send by two)

Like i have :

> Hello i am one (send by one)
>
> How are you (send by one)
>
> Hello one ! I am two (send by two)
>
> Fine (send by two)

Like my problem is that i don't know how to set two repo in one .. i want a repo with the messages received and sended

Thx for all that will try to help ! I hope that you understand my bad explanation :)

Nb : The entity :

```
<?php
```

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

```
/**
* @MongoDB\Document()
*/
class MessageUser implements \JsonSerializable
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $content;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="timestamp")
 */
protected $sendAt;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="boolean")
 */
protected $read;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="integer")
 */
protected $idTransmitter;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="integer")
 */
protected $idReceiver;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return $this
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string $content
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set sendAt
 *
 * @param $sendAt
 * @return $this
 */
public function setSendAt($sendAt)
{
    $this->sendAt = $sendAt;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sendAt
 *
 * @return $sendAt
 */
public function getSendAt()
{
    return $this->sendAt;
}

/**
 * Set read
 *
 * @param boolean $read
 * @return $this
 */
public function setRead($read)
{
    $this->read = $read;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get read
 *
 * @return boolean $read
 */
public function getRead()
{
    return $this->read;
}

/**
 * Set idTransmitter
 *
 * @param integer $idTransmitter
 * @return $this
 */
public function setIdTransmitter($idTransmitter)
{
    $this->idTransmitter = $idTransmitter;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idTransmitter
 *
 * @return integer $idTransmitter
 */
public function getIdTransmitter()
{
    return $this->idTransmitter;
}

/**
 * Set idReceiver
 *
 * @param integer $idReceiver
 * @return $this
 */
public function setIdReceiver($idReceiver)
{
    $this->idReceiver = $idReceiver;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idReceiver
 *
 * @return integer $idReceiver
 */
public function getIdReceiver()
{
    return $this->idReceiver;
}

function jsonSerialize()
{
    return array(
        "id"       => $this->id,
        "content" => $this->content,
        "transmitter"  => $this->idTransmitter,
        "Receiver" => $this->idReceiver,
        "send_at" => $this->sendAt,
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please join your `AppBundle:MessageUser ` entity please

Comment: sure i do that in a second, done :)

Comment: What about change your `findBy` ordering to `sendAt` instead of `id` ?

Comment: that will not resolve the problem ... in the repo i have only the message send by someone to someone and i would like the messages send and received

Comment: the order is fine trust me i just want to know how can i set one repo from two repo

Comment: What is the difference between `message send by someone to someone` and `messages send and received` ? Are they stored in differents collections ? 
I never had this kind of problem with mongo sorry, with mysql it's just a good join.

Comment: I store the message with an id for receiver and one for the sender so when i try to make a repo and get all message for make the conversation (exemple with user two and one) i have to make two repo (image that i want to print messages for user one) i will have to make a repo for the message he send to user two and one other with the message that he receive from user two ... and i want to make only one repo with both (sended and received)

Comment: because when i will want to print that's not good if i do it with 2 repo it will print one repo and after the other ... so all the messages send and after all the message received

Comment: i am thinking to something : i can try to set automatically an id for the conversation and i will make the repo from this id (i will try to set the id automatically when the receiver and sender are the same) but will be a bit long and difficult if you have a better idea .. ?

Comment: Could you join the [Symfony Dev slack](https://join.slack.com/t/symfony-devs/shared_invite/enQtNDA3MTI3MTIwODA3LTg2OTE3ZjI1MTczMWQ2MTk3MWRjNTg5ZTk3NWM2ZWE3Y2UxYTM5M2E0YjZjYTlmYjA3Yjk4MzkxM2E0MmI2MmE) ? I'm french that will be easier to share ;)
I got the same pseudo, just mp me